# Element Selector Not Working In Stylesheet for Worpress Site

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to style the following code in a Wordpress site but it is not working on:

```css
.site-info {
text-align: center;
color: black;
 }

.site-info p{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<footer class="site-footer">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="site-info">
            <p>&copy; <?php echo absint( date_i18n( 'Y' ) ) 
   . ' ' . esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?></p>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </div><!-- .wrapper -->
</footer><!-- .site-footer -->
```

For some reason, the color is not changing as I would have intended it to.

Am I using the selectors incorrectly, or does this have to do with the code between the `<p></p>`?

Comment: What color is not changing correctly?

Comment: The p element wont change

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the site and the specific area where the issue exists

Comment: it is on local host

Comment: Are you able to use the Browser's Inspector to see how the styles are being applied? The most likely cause is a specificity issue, and a style somewhere else is overriding the one you're tryng to set.

Comment: Okay. Try debugging it on a browser

Comment: @Justmatt other css will work except color?

Comment: no style changes show up for selectors used in the footer. i can apply a generic h1, etc, tag and the style will inherit from further up the style sheet

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.site-info {
display:block;
text-align: center;
color: black;
 }
.site-info p{
color: red;
}
```

Comment: `display: block` will not affect the colour of the text, which is the problem being described.

Comment: I can see that the style is being inherited form the body. Basically, everything in the footer can inherit from styles further up the style sheet. When i use selectors in the footer, the styles have no effect

Comment: @Justmatt This may seem like a silly question, but does `.siteinfo p` appear in the style sheet when you view it separately? If there are no other styles that would be overriding the ones you've created it could be that the styles are not being loaded, or the site is cached.

Answer (score 0):

I Make Changes and Nothing Happens :

**- Clearing the Browser Cache**

Normally, to see the changes on your page, you click the Refresh button on the browser toolbar or press the F5 key on your keyboard. CTRL+F5 or use incognito mode.

**- Server-side Caching**

Sever side cache need to clean it manually

**- A WordPress Cache Plugin**

If there is cache plugin you need to clear cache from plugin

**- View Source**

open a CSS in new tab and check is CSS element appear in css. if not then just add plugin called WP Version in Query String Modifier

Plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-version-in-query-string-modifier/

**- Override existing CSS**

You have to use !important element for existing element.

```
.site-info {
text-align: center;
color: black;
 }

.site-info p{
color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out. I had copy and pasted alot of css and was missing some closing brackets in the one of the previous sections. Thanks for looking at this, its really appreciated